# Отправка POST запроса без формы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, я делаю сайт - что-то наподобие магазина.
При заказе нужно указать почту `<input type="text" name="mail" size="20">`,
всё хорошо, оно отправляет запрос с почтой, но мне нужно, чтобы ещё отправляло ид товара и название товара. вот код ид товара и наименования.

```
<tr>
  <td>Id товара: </td>
  <td><div name="Id"><?php echo $_GET['Id']; ?></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Название:</td>
  <td><div name="Name"><?php echo $_GET['Name'];?></div></td>
</tr>
```

Надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: "оно отправляет запрос с почтой" - как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr>
  <td>Id товара: </td>
  <td><div name="Id">
    <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<?php echo $_GET['Id']; ?>" />
    <?php echo $_GET['Id']; ?>
  </div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Название:</td>
  <td><div name="Name">
    <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="<?php echo $_GET['Name']; ?>" />
    <?php echo $_GET['Name'];?>
  </div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: ееее! [XSS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь скрытыми полями формы `<input type="hidden">`.
Просто поместите нужное значение в атрибут `value`. К примеру:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="<?=$_GET['Id']; ?>">
```